# Cocoapods: pod lib lint giving me 273 errors, all seem to come from SnapKit

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to write a Cocoapod library that uses SnapKit as a dependency, and the Example project is working fine - the installation of SnapKit worked fine, but when I run `pod lib lint`, it's detecting a ton of errors from SnapKit.

My first thought is that Cocoapods is using a different Swift version than SnapKit when detecting that dependency, but I was wondering how I would remedy that problem, or if someone thinks it's a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my hunch that it was a Swift versioning issue was correct. Saw on SnapKit's Readme that Swift 2.x requires SnapKit version 0.22.0, whereas version 3.0.0 and greater is Swift 3.x.

Before, my podspec had the following line for SnapKit:

```
s.dependency 'SnapKit'
```

So I belive the lint was inspecting the current version of SnapKit (which is in Swift 3), so I changed that line to this:

```
s.dependency 'SnapKit', '~> 0.22.0'
```

and passed lint.